# Toggle a div that is not a sibling

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I need help with the folloiwng please...
I need to click an icon to open a hidden div that is not the next element.
This is my markup (The record div is repeated a number of times on the page...

```
<div class='record'>
    <div class="marker_name left"><a href="marker.php?id=11444">Name</a></div>
    <div class="clear table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td"><div class="icon_32"><img src="images/flags/DE.png"></div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="icon_32 type_sprite spr_ASN"></div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="icon_32"><img src="images/site/web_32.png"></a></div></div>
            <div class="td mid"><div class="bearing icon_32 bearing_N"></div></div>
            <div class="td mid"><div class="distance">0kM</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="trigger icon_32"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>List of features</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is my jQuery where you can see the different things I have tried all to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hidden').hide();

        $('.trigger').click(function()
                {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                //$(this).next().next().toggle();
                //$(this).nextAll('.hidden').toggle();
                //$(".record").next(".hidden").toggle();
                $(".record").nextAll(".hidden").toggle();
                }
        );
});
```

The div with the class "trigger" should open the div with the class "hidden" and ideally, close any other class with hidden that is now visible.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        var el = $(this).toggleClass('active')
                        .closest('.record')
                        .find('.hidden').toggle();

        $('.hidden:visible').not(el).hide();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7wz4/)

Comment: Wow, wasnt expecting an answer that quick, thats worked exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();

    var $recs = $(".record"),
        $hiddens = $recs.find(".hidden"),
        $triggers = $recs.find(".trigger");
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        var $rec = $(this).closest('.record');
        var $hidden = $rec.find('.hidden').toggle();

        $hiddens.not($hidden).hide();
        $triggers.not(this).removeClass('active')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9DuTK/)

Answer (score 0):

If you find the parent record and then the hidden child that should work:

```
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('.record').find('.hidden').toggle();
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active').closest('.record').find('.hidden').toggle();
    });
});
```

This hides all of the `.hidden` div's, then when a trigger is clicked, it hides them all again, looks at the trigger  and finds the closest `.record` up the dom tree, finds the `.hidden` within it, and then toggles the visibility of it.

Comment: Of course, it hides the current `.hidden` as well, and then toggle's it, so it will always be visible ?

Comment: Good point! On reflection I would go the route you have shown.